# Force SQL Server to close result sets on DML queries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pdo, sqlsrv

I have a PHP program that uses the PDO::sqlsrv driver to query against an MS SQL Server database.

This has some strange behavior. If I have MARS enabled (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/using-multiple-active-result-sets-mars?view=sql-server-ver15), which is the default, and try to start a transaction at some points, I get the following error:

```
["42000",3988,"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session."]
```

It appears that this is because some active result sets need to get closed down. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of how to determine what threads are running in the session. I turned off MARS to try to better determine what queries are not shutting down properly, and after any insert/update I get the following error:

```
IMSSP
-61
The connection cannot process this operation because there is a statement with pending results.  To make the connection available for other queries, either fetch all results or cancel or free the statement.  For more information, see the product documentation about the MultipleActiveResultSets connection option.
```

Apparently any insert/update is creating a result set that needs its cursor closed.

Manually closing the cursor after each DML statement fixes the issue. This is quite inconvenient, and doesn't seem like it should be the behavior of SQL Server to create a result set that is meaningless (DML statements don't return any rows).

Is this the intended behavior (that DML statements need manual closing of the associated cursor)?

Is there a way to stop this behavior (close the cursors automatically for DML statements)?

Is there a way to close all the open result sets on a connection, so I can start a transaction (that would be easy to implement)?

Comment: Seems like you should be posting your PHP code here and tagging that, so that we can see why you are disposing of your connections properly,

Comment: DML doesn't create resultsets, except in the case of the OUTPUT clause, or a trigger returns a resultset.  You'll get a DONE_IN_PROC message, unless you SET NOCOUNT ON, and some client stacks don't automatically process the DONE_IN_PROC message.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Trying to fetch anything from the resulting statement doesn't return anything; but it seems like there is an open cursor on the result (until it is manually closed).

Comment: That could be, depending on how the client driver is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

It's quiet simple to close a `ResultSet`. First of all I want to mention, that even when MARS is disabled two `ResultSet`s can be used together, but with restrictions.

When using `PDO_SQLSRV` the use of the Method `ResultSet::current()` places a serverside pointer `CURSOR` to remember the current row. So you can go on iterating later in your code. If this `CURSOR` is placed serverside you aren't able to use a second `ResultSet`.

## Ways around

### Unset ResultSet

```
/* e.g. get first row of first resultset */
$result = $resultSet1->current();

unset($resultSet1);

/* e.g. get first row of second resultset */
$anotherResult = $resultSet2->current();
```

### Rewind Cursor

```
/* e.g. get first row of first resultset */
$result = $resultSet1->current();

$resultSet1->rewind();

/* e.g. get first row of second resultset */
$anotherResult = $resultSet2->current();
```

### Loop over ResultSet

```
/* e.g. get first row of first resultset */
$result = null;
foreach ($resultSet1 as $row) {
    $result = $row;
    break;
}

/* e.g. do something with second resultset */
foreach ($resultSet2 as $row) {
    /* do something with $row */
}
```

### Clientside Cursors

You can also set an PDO options to use clientside cursors. So the complete result will be placed into the RAM and the cursor will be emulated inside.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/cursor-types-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15#client-side-cursors-and-the-sqlsrv-driver